# Updated bounds or references for an old Erdős problem –– coloring the plane with multiple forbidden distances?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, graph-colorings, open-problems

Define a graph $G_1$ where the vertices of $G_1$ are the points of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a pair of vertices $p, q$ is connected by an edge if and only if the Euclidean distance $d(p,q) =1$. The Hadwiger–Nelson unit-coloring problem asks for the "chromatic number of the plane": i.e. what is $\chi( G_1 )$? The best known bounds are that $5 \le \chi( G_1 ) \le 7$, with the lower bound improved from 4 to 5 in a breakthrough result by Aubrey de Grey in 2018.

Apparently Erdős asked about the following variant. Let $S =\{ d_1, d_2, \dots, d_k \}$ be a set of positive numbers. Define $G_S$ with vertices corresponding to points in the plane, and edges corresponding to pairs of points at any distance $d_1$, $d_2$, ..., or $d_k$.

Let $f(k)$ denote the maximum chromatic number $\max \chi(G_S)$ as $S$ ranges over all sets of $k$ positive numbers. Clearly $f(k) \le 7^k$, so $f(k)$ is well defined and is finite for every $k$.

**Roughly, how does $f(k)$ grow as $k \to \infty$?**

According to Soifer (in The Mathematical Coloring Book), Erdős wrote that "it is not hard to see" that $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(k)}{k} \to \infty.$$
As pointed out in the comments, this follows from the fact that a square grid with $\sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n}$ points only realizes $O \left( n / \sqrt{\log n} \right)$ distinct distances.

What are the best known upper and lower bounds on $f(k)$?

It was recently [shown by Exoo and Ismailescu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.13177) that $f(2) \ge 6$, but I'm not aware of any nontrivial lower bounds for $f(k)$ even for $k \ge 3$.

Any more information for small $k$ would be great, but I'm especially interested in the rate of growth as $k \to \infty$. Erdős apparently asked whether $f(k)$ grows only polynomially fast, and I am wondering whether this is still an open problem.

Comment: For the "it is not hard to see" lower bound, I think it suffices to consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_distinct_distances_problem and the upper bound there.  That is, arrange $n$ points in a $\sqrt{n}\times\sqrt{n}$ square grid.  The number of distinct distances is at most $k = cn/\sqrt{\log n}$; forbid those.  Then no two of the $n=\omega(k)$ points can be colored the same color.

Comment: Thanks aorq, I just realized this too. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> Erdos apparently asked whether $f(k)$ grows only polynomially fast, and I am wondering whether this is still an open problem.

This is very much an open problem. Other than using a set with few distinct distances, (which corresponds to an independent set in the graph), there have been no ideas to lower bound this problem asymptotically for large $k$. That is, the much weaker question of improving the lower bound to $$f(k)>Ck\sqrt{\log k}$$ for a constant $C > 1.4194\dots$ is open, where this constant is coming from distinct distances in subsets of the hexagonal lattice.

See Section 2 and Problem 4 of the Problems section of *[The Chromatic Number of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Multiple Forbidden Distances.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12312)*

### Current state of knowledge

**Notation:** For a finite set of distances $A$, let $\chi(\mathbb{R}^{2},A)$ denote the chromatic number of the graph with vertex set $\mathbb{R}^2$ and edge set $E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \|x-y\|_2\in A\}.$ Define $$\overline{\chi}(\mathbb{R}^2,m):=\max_{A:\ |A|=m}\chi(\mathbb{R}^2,A).$$

#### Existing Bounds

The best lower bound I know of for $\overline{\chi}(\mathbb{R}^2,m)$ is $g^{-1}(m)$, where $g(n)$ is the minimum number of distinct distances among $n$ points in the plane, and it is an open problem if there exists a constant $C_1 > 1.4194\dots$ such that $$\overline{\chi}(\mathbb{R}^2,m)\geq C_1m\sqrt{\log m}(1+o(1)).$$ More generally, it is an open problem if there exists $C_2>1$ such that $\overline{\chi}(\mathbb{R}^2,m)>C_2g^{-1}(m)$. As for the upper bound, the best general upper bound is exponential, as you mentioned in your question.

#### Specific Distance Sets

However, for specific distance sets, we can give the order of growth almost exactly. Section 2 of *[The Chromatic Number of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Multiple Forbidden Distances.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12312)* discusses the specific case of $n=2$. The following Theorem is proven there, but was generally known to those interested in this problem:

> **Theorem:** For a set of distances $\mathcal{D}=\{d_{1}<d_{2}<\cdots\}$, let
> $\mathcal{D}(m)=\{d_{1},\dots,d_{m}\}$ denote the $m$ smallest distances in $\mathcal{D}$. There exists a set of distances $\mathcal{D}_\Delta$ such that
> $$\left|\chi(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{D}_{\Delta}(m))-1.75m\sqrt{\log m}\right|\leq 0.34 m\sqrt{\log m}(1+o(1)).$$

The specific distance set here is $$\mathcal{D}_\Delta=\{n\geq 1: \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z} n=x^2+xy+y^2\}.$$ We have similar bound for the set $\mathcal{D}_{\square}=\{n\geq 1: \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z} n=x^2+y^2\}.$ See section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12312 for more details.

#### Further improvements?

Both $\mathcal{D}_\Delta$ and $\mathcal{D}_\square$ are natural subsets of distances to consider, and this result suggests to me that to substantially improve the lower bound, one must work with relatively strange distance sets. I believe that $C m\sqrt{\log m}$ is close to the right answer, and the upper bounds are lacking.